# Cómo pasar un array de PHP a JS y mostrarla en una función?

Tags: php, javascript

tengo un array llamado `$array_especificaciones` el cual si le hago un print_r me muestra lo siguiente:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_especificacion] => 1 [id_projecte] => 1 [nombre_especificacion] => espe1 [dificultad] => facil [descripcion] => Crear boton [tiempo] => 01:00:00 [id_usuario] => 1 [acabado] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [id_especificacion] => 2 [id_projecte] => 1 [nombre_especificacion] => esp2 [dificultad] => facil [descripcion] => hola [tiempo] => 02:00:00 [id_usuario] => 1 [acabado] => 0 ) )
```

Necesito pasar $array_especificaciones desde PHP a una función de JS, de momento he probado pasándolo asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var array_especificaciones = <?php echo json_encode($array_especificaciones);?>;
        divEspecificacionesPB(array_especificaciones);
    </script>
```

Es decir, abro un script dentro del php, cogo la variable y llamo a la funcion, el problema vien cuando desde JS intento recorrer ese array, solo me muestra "unidefined" (como si no tuviera valor el array que paso) o "[Object object, Object object"].

Saludos y gracias.

**EDIT**

Muchas gracias, ahora se me muestra por consola, todo correcto, sabes como podría ahora mostrar cada uno de los resultado en una "p" de HTML?

Mira, el bucle que me has pasado he intentado modificarlo así:

```
var n = array_especificaciones.length;
    for(var i = 0;i<n;i++){
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        div.appendChild(p);
        p.innerText = array_especificaciones[i]; 
    }
```

Si lo meto como tu me has dicho, con el console.log me muestra los datos así:

```
Object { id_especificacion: "1", id_projecte: "1", nombre_especificacion: "espe1", dificultad: "facil", descripcion: "Crear boton", tiempo: "01:00:00", id_usuario: "1", acabado: "0" }
Object { id_especificacion: "2", id_projecte: "1", nombre_especificacion: "esp2", dificultad: "facil", descripcion: "hola", tiempo: "02:00:00", id_usuario: "1", acabado: "0" }
```

Cuando lo intento hacer como te indico yo me muestra:

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo directamente así:

```
var array_especificaciones = <?php echo json_encode($array_especificaciones) ?>;
```

Para recorrer ese array, tienes muchas formas:
Por ejemplo:

```
var n = array_especificaciones.length; //obtienes la longitud
for(var i = 0;i<n;i++){
    console.log(array_especificaciones[i]);
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var array_especificaciones = [
 { 
  id_especificacion: "1", 
  id_projecte: "1", 
  nombre_especificacion: "espe1", 
  dificultad: "facil", 
  descripcion: "Crear boton", 
  tiempo: "01:00:00", 
  id_usuario: "1", 
  acabado: "0" 
  },
 { 
  id_especificacion: "2", 
  id_projecte: "1", 
  nombre_especificacion: "esp2", 
  dificultad: "facil", 
  descripcion: "hola", 
  tiempo: "02:00:00", 
  id_usuario: "1", 
  acabado: "0"
 }
];

var parrafo = '';
var n = array_especificaciones.length;
for(var i = 0;i<n;i++){//para cada elemento (array) de tu array principal;

 parrafo = $('<p>'); //creas un parrafo
 var array = array_especificaciones[i]; //obtienes el array secundario
 var keys = Object.keys(array); //obtienes las claves/llaves de dicho array.
 var m = keys.length; //obtienes la longitud de tu array secundario
 for(j=0;j<m;j++){
  var span = $('<span>').text(keys[j]); //creas un span para escribir la llave/key y le insertas el texto de la llave.
  var span2 = $('<span>').text(array[keys[j]]); //creas otro span para escribir el valor de esa key y le insertas dicho valor.
  parrafo.append(span,span2);//metes los dos span en tu parrafo
 }
$('body').append(parrafo); //insertas el parrafo en el body

}




});
```

```css
p {
border:1px solid grey;
}

span {
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

UPDATE 2:

Lo que te ocurre es que cada uno de los valores de tu array principal es a su vez otro array. Es decir, tu array esta compuesto de arrays, y estos estan compuestos de valores. Al intentar introducir el valor de tu array principal en un parrafo (p), no puede ya que no es un valor "literal" como tal, sino un conjunto de valores.

UPDATE 3:

Si quieres mostrar todos los resultados, por ejemplo, aquí tienes una idea (es sólo una idea. Hay varias formas de hacerlo):

Comment: Si lohago así me salta el siguiente error: SyntaxError: invalid arrow-function arguments (parentheses around the arrow-function may help)

Comment: @Marc perdona, estaba despistado. Prueba ahora con el update que he hecho

Comment: Ahora no me salta error, pero no sé como recorrer ese array en javascript, alguna idea ?

Comment: @Marc update para ver como puedes recorrerlo. Mira en la consola el resultado (F12 y pestaña console).

Comment: Buenas, he editado la pregunta, mírala por favor.

Comment: @Marc pon un ejemplo de como quieres que se impriman los datos, porque sin ver tu html es muy dificil ayudarte.

Comment: No tengo un html como tal, lo que necesito es recorrer cada uno de los valores del array y añadirlo dentro de un parágrafo, así:

`var n = array_especificaciones.length;
    for(var i = 0;i<n;i++){
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        div.appendChild(p);
        p.innerText = array_especificaciones[i]; 
    }`

Comment: @Marc ahí tienes una idea. Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de JavaScript, podemos usar la etiqueta PHP para hacer eco de la variable PHP asignándola a una variable JavaScript. Por ejemplo, asigne un valor Metallica a una variable $var dentro de las etiquetas PHP. Escriba una etiqueta script y dentro de ella, escriba una etiqueta PHP.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).